# Nested vue instance not returning computed: function values

Tags: symfony, vue.js, twig, vuejs2

I'm using twig and in my base I have a new Vue instance that assigns everything to #app, which is a section right after the body tag.

In users.html page, I extend this base.twig, reason why I can't have the same code onto the base.twig is because some data is only passed to the vue on the users controller, so I get errors on any other pages since the users data isn't set.

This is what I have on my **base.twig**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        hideNav: false,
        userMenuDropdown: false,

        showModal: false
    }
});
```

And in my **users.html** I have:

```
var UsersPage = new Vue({
    el: '.users__main',
    data: {
        search_users: '',
        users: {{ users|raw }}
    },
    computed: {
        filteredUsers,
    }
});

function filteredUsers(){
    var self = this;
    return this.users.filter(function(cust){
        return cust.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search_users.toLowerCase())>=0;
    });
}
```

I'm simply trying to search for an user, everything works if I take off the first vue instance that references **#app**, not **.users__main.**

I have setup a jsfiddle to further explain the exact issue, [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/a253e0sm/1/) (does not work) has both vue instances, one in the base.twig and the other in the user.html file, [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/a253e0sm/2/) does not contain both instances (works).

I was messing with components for this but I wasn't able to get that going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to figure it out after reading the documentation, I wound up using a component with [inline-template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates).

In my base.twig I create one and only 1 instance of Vue.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

And now in my **user.html** file that extends the **base.twig** I created a component.

This wound up being the component and how it was used to have a search function working that I provided in the jsfiddle example in the question.

```
Vue.component('user-search', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            search_users: '',
            users: {{ users|raw }} // this here is json_encoded data from twig passed from the php framework controller
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredUsers,
    }
});

function filteredUsers(){
    var self = this;
    return this.users.filter(function(cust){
        return cust.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search_users.toLowerCase())>=0;
    });
}
```

And to use the component(showing how to use it based on my code):

```
<user-search inline-template>
    <input type="text" v-model="search_users">
    <!-- rest of the code with the for loop -->
</user-search>
```

Comment: You can't use interpolation `users: {{ users|raw }}` inside object definition.

Comment: @WaldemarIce It's working so far, that's a twig data passed from the controller, same as it would be if it were normal php code. I could use axios or a normal http request to get the data strictly via javascript, but since I can get it easily via my php framework it's a lot easier.

Comment: You are using new Vue inside new Vue?

Comment: No, now I only have 1 new Vue({{ ... }}) instance; in my base.twig that attaches itself to #app (a section that wraps all html code after the body tag), I then extend base.twig to my other view files, and now I'm using components, so only 1 vue instance has been created. Am I doing anything wrong at this point?

Comment: But as I see in your first fiddle, section `.users__main` is nested in div `app`, so you are nesting second Vue instance into first instance.

Comment: I was doing it wrong, I learned, and you have just sure assured me that I was doing it wrong. I'll update my answer. The reason why I had two instances of Vue was because I didn't study components deep enough, I thought a template was always required within a component.

Comment: Just use one complete instance. No matter in which file, because php is composing your page before it arrives in browser. So, use only one instance for whole `div#app`.